# Invalid chai property: browser when trying to run a test on puppeteer

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, automation, puppeteer, chai

i'm trying to run a test on a website using puppeteer and i want to use 'expect' assertion from chai but i keep getting this error and that my test failed.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer') 
const expect = require('chai').expect

describe('My First Puppeteer Test  ',  () => { 
    it( 'should launch the browser', async function() {  
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
            headless: false,
            slowMo: 10,
            devtools: false,
            defaultViewport: null,
            args: ['--start-maximized'] 
    })
        const page = await browser.newPage() 
        await page.goto('http://example.com') 
        const title = await page.title()
        const url = page.url()
        const text = await page.$eval('h1', Element => Element.textContent) 
        const count = await page.$$eval('p', Element => Element.length)
        
        expect(title).to.be.a('string', 'Example Domain')
        expect(url).to.include('example.com')
        expect(text).to.browser.a('string', 'example domain')
        expect(count).to.equal(2)
        await browser.close()
        

    })
})
```

what's wrong with it?
do i need to add something in order for this to work?

this is the message i get from terminal

```
 My First Puppeteer Test
    1) should launch the browser


  0 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1) My First Puppeteer Test
       should launch the browser:
     Error: Invalid Chai property: browser
      at Object.proxyGetter [as get] (node_modules\chai\lib\chai\utils\proxify.js:78:17)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests\example.test.js:25:24)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Comment: `to.browser.a.`? What's that? Did you mean `to.be.a.`?

Comment: turns owt instead of ``` to.be.a. ``` it auto filled browser